# 404 for new router from a specific device

Tags: networking, router, tcpip

I just swapped my old home router for a Netgear AC1600 (UK). I'm writing this on a Surface Book that's connected to the new router via a Surface Hub. So, the internet connection is good but when I try to reach the router config page at 192.168.0.1 I get a 404 error. I tried ipconfig /renew and rebooting the Surface Book but neither helped.

Ipconfig from a command line tells me that my IPv4 address is 192.168.0.2 and the Default Gateway is 192.168.0.1. I am able to ping this default gateway address ok.

I have another old laptop in the house that's connected directly to the new router via ethernet. This has been assigned an IPv4 address of 192.168.0.10. From here, I am able to reach the new router's config page from a browser at 192.168.0.1.

Any ideas what could be preventing the Surface Book reaching the new router's config page?

The error is: HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
The problem client PC is running Windows 10 pro with all current Windows updates applied. It is not joined to a domain but is a member of a workgroup called WORKGROUP.

Here's what Chrome displays:
[image: 404]

And results from an ipconfig /all:

[image: ipconfig]

Comment: Can you give us the exact error with as much detail as possible?

Comment: A 404 error is a return code from a web server. So your browser is reaching a web server of some sort, but that server is claiming it doesn’t have the page you are requesting. 

Is there any chance your browser isn’t going to simply "http://192.168.0.1/", but instead maybe it’s auto-completing to some longer URL?

Comment: Thanks for your replies and sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I've now added to a couple of screen grabs to give more detail